# ARRAYFORMULA REGEXMATCH for multiple rows formula application

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

When I have a column of source values which in I would like to seek for particular values listed in other column (search should be case sensitive and match the occurrence on any position in the source string) and return the number of the first row where it matches, I use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A; "(?i).*?"&C1); ROW(A:A))))
```

But what if I'd like to `ARRAYFORMULA` it(?) to make the same operation for rows below. Now I simply copy the formula down but maybe there is a way? I've tried to apply another `ARRAYFORMULA` inside but I failed, unfortunately.

Example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15Eu9cRi3sgzVnIbQNhWdCTUVCY-t87YVtS9KZKCfNlE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH("*"&C1:C6&"*"; A:A; 0))
```

[image: 0]